# Why is opera bolding fonts

Tags: jquery, css, browser

[link](http://impactweb.pl/operafont/) - I dont get it. I dont include any another font-face, I've reseted css, I've disabled headers bold and every browser is showing its as nice, thin letter, but Opera just show it bold.

[image]

Comment: It may help if you make a properly-constructed HTML document instead of just a style tag and a header tag with no structure.

Comment: Have you tried actually "bolding" it to see if it's in fact bolding it or if it's just displaying the font with a higher font-weight?  Different browsers tend to render subtly different font-weights which can be more noticeable at different sizes.

Comment: You should have more than one (obscure) font-face in the declaration. `M1cthin` doesn't cut it.

Comment: Always quote the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: can't reproduce this in Opera 11.61 - looks exactly as in Chrom (like the first case in your screenshot).

Comment: it happens since i've updated to 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that opera bolds `h1` elements by default. (Although you said you tried un-bolding it)

Try this first:

```
h1 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

if that doesn't work, then maybe opera has a different definition of normal. In which case you should do something like this:

```
h1 {
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

or if you wan't even a little more control you could do something like:

```
h1 {
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Comment: @user1785870 I typically just google search something like "css font-weight" and the documentation usually has a list of accepted values. That one I knew from experience, though

Answer (score 0):

Neither `font-weight: light` nor `font-style: light` is valid CSS. Validate your HTML and your CSS first.